# Unable to load Symbol in Web Map

Tags: arcmap, symbology, arcgis-portal

We just installed portal 10.6.1, completely new environment... almost everything appears to be functioning normally except point symbology configuration will not load within a webmap

[image: screenshot from webmap. also when I click the drop down it does not respond].

We're seeing the same behavior in the default symbology settings within the item settings for point layers.  I also checked out the REST endpoint and noticed that the drawing info section looks different that in previous versions... but perhaps this is just a new syntax?

[image: screenshot of REST endpoint for layer].

Polygon and polyline symbology appears to be working fine--seems isolated to point layers.

I've also noticed that all the basemaps are inaccessible through the basemap widget (just shows as loading)... not sure if this is a related issue or not.

[image: just shows loading symbol]

What we've tried so far:

1. white-listed ESRI-specified URLs thinking that it might allow accessibility to these features
2. re-indexed the portal

Has anyone experienced this and know how to fix it?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue in two of three of our Portal environments. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @dbusses I'd open developer tools in the browser and watch the console for JavaScript errors or the Network tab. It may provide a clue where it's falling over.

Comment: Did anyone had any luck resolving this issue ?